# How to avoid Array Out of Bound Exception in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to write code in Java (part of mapreduce job) to check a sentence for certain keywords, when any keyword found in the sentence, it should check the sentence up to 2 words before the keyword and/or up to 3 words after. if it finds a match it outputs something.

I am writing a code to iterate through 3 `ArrayLists` of Strings as follows:

1- iterate through `Arraylist1<String)` and check `if ArrayList1.get(i)= ArrayList2.get(j)`. if equals, proceed to 2 (below), otherwise `i++`.

2- Iterate through ArraList3. Check up to 2 words before `ArraList1[i]` and up to 3 words after `ArrayList1[i]`. If in this range it finds a match within `ArrayList3`, it should output something.

Now the problem lies with implementing the conditions of 2 words before and 3 words after. Because it needs to consider a lot of conditions depending on the size of the sentence (i.e. size of `ArrayList1`).

Example: if you are at 1st or 2nd word of the sentence,you need to check 3 words after only And 1 word before and 3 words after (also depending on the size of the sentence).

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokensList.size(); i++) {

  keywordsListLoop:

    for (int j = 0; j < keywordsList.size(); j++) {

      if (tokensList.get(i).startsWith(keywordsList.get(j)) == true)

        for (int e = i - 2; e < i + 4; e++) {
          boolean flag = false;
          // I think the rules need to go here
          for (int g = 0; g < posWordsList.size(); g++) {
            // or perhaps here :s
            if (tokensList.get(e).compareTo(posWordsList.get(g)) == 0) {

              word.set(keywordsList.get(j));
              context.write(word, one);
              flag = true;
              break; //breaks out of Inner loop (PosWords loop)
            }
          }

          if (flag)
            break; //breaks out of outter loop ( e loop) 
          break keywordsListLoop; //need to make sure this actually breaks out of keywords loop
        }
    }

  //now check next token
```

Comment: Assuming your code is correct and since the only call that could result in the exception would be `tokensList.get(e)`, you could do `e = Math.max(0, i - 2); e < Math.min( tokensList.size() - 1, i + 4); ...` to get the correct boundaries.

Comment: There are methods in the `List` you can use to avoid using so many for loops like `contains` and `indexOf`. May I suggest you look at the [List documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I will give that a try now.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for the advice. Do these ( contains and indexOf) also work for ArrayLists? I opened the link but I couldn't be sure if they apply to ArrayList as well :s

Comment: Correction: I forgot it is `e < ...` so the `-1` is wrong, it should be `e < Math.min( tokensList.size(), i + 4);`

Comment: `ArrayList implements List` and thus the documentation on `List` applies to `ArrayList` as well. In fact, it should apply to all implementations of `List` that adhere to the contract and if any implementation differs in a way it should clearly state so (though such implementation would cause so many problems that they probably don't exist on purpose).

Comment: Hi there. I checked contains method, but does it work in place of this: >> if (tokensList.get(i).startsWith(keywordsList.get(j)), because here I want to check if it starts with it and Not if it just contains ? I don't think it'll work, am I right?

Comment: Yes that's right. At that level you have to use `String` methods

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and reply @Joakim Danielson. I did use contain methods and so my code is indeed neater now. And it runs and gives the results I want. Again thank you both so much!

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing - structure your code, having 4 nested loops is insane. Try to write some function with some nice description of what they are doing and dont have more than 2 loops inside each other.

To your question, you have this `if (tokensList.get(e)`, while `e` is set as `int e = i - 2` and because `i` initially starts as `int i = 0`, then you can check the `-2` or `-1`. Same goes for upper bound, you have `e < i + 4` which is `+4` more than is your list size.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I am actually brand new to Java and don't have experience in writing functions. I understand that the prolem is the initialisation and the only solution I can write is a lot of if conditions within. Basically, my question is about finding a better way around this.